# how to create TabHost v4 like view for previous versions on 2.3

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs, fragment-tab-host

i am new in android scratching my head from many hours.

Is it possible to custom or have view of Tabs like following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKZXa.png

on previous versions like froyo(2.2) and gingerbread(2.3)..

--> I have tried ABS but it is showing default view only like:

http://envyandroid.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/tabs-up.png

any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "showing default view only" means. ActionBarSherlock certainly supports action bar tabs, and you can achieve a similar look using `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator.

Comment: Thanks for reply..I have edited my question
and Tabbed indicator support similar view i mentioned on froyo(2.2) and gingerbread(2.3) also? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Your second screenshot has nothing to do with ActionBarSherlock. It is showing a `TabHost`.

Comment: So how can i achieve look like first screenshot on versions froyo(2.2) and gingerbread(2.3)?

Comment: Tab Indicator is working fine on these version. Thanks for suggestion mate..:)